# Define composite primary key in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, entity-framework

I have a table which has no primary key defined. When adding this to my DataModel the tool generates the following message:

> Errors Found During Generation:
>   warning 6013: The table/view
>   'CHARGE_DETAILS' does not have a primary key defined
>   and no valid primary key could be inferred. This table/view has been
>   excluded. To use the entity, you will need to review your schema, add
>   the correct keys, and uncomment it.

I cannot modify the table in any way - however I reckon I could construct a composite key from two columns in order to satisfy these requirements.

However [it appears](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399579.aspx) that within the `EntityType` element `Key` can only contain **zero or one** elements.

So how would I instruct EF to treat two columns as a key?

Comment: @flindeberg - Unfortunately not, feel free to put a bounty on it though

Answer (score 1):

You can create composite primary key on the database side. Do you use ODP.Net? It will automatically map your database pk.

Comment: Like I said - the database has no key defined and I cannot modify it

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem today, I did a quick and dirty to get it working. I just commented out the defining query in the *.edmx*-file for the given entity.

"Original":

```
<EntitySet Name="CODES" EntityType="Self.CODES" store:Type="Tables" store:Schema="PIZZA">
  <DefiningQuery>
   SELECT 
    "CODES"."LINE" AS "LINE", 
    "CODES"."TEXT" AS "TEXT", 
    "CODES"."MODULE" AS "MODULE", 
    "CODES"."DEFAULT" AS "DEFAULT"
  </DefiningQuery>
</EntitySet>
```

After modification:

```
<EntitySet Name="CODES" EntityType="Self.CODES" store:Type="Tables" store:Schema="PIZZA">
  <!--<DefiningQuery>
   SELECT 
    "CODES"."LINE" AS "LINE", 
    "CODES"."TEXT" AS "TEXT",
    "CODES"."MODULE" AS "MODULE", 
    "CODES"."DEFAULT" AS "DEFAULT"
  </DefiningQuery>-->
</EntitySet>
```

In my case this worked, but I assume it does not work in every case. I'm using `LINE` and `MODULE` as a composite key. I'm not doing anything fancy with this table, just raw inserts, so it works.

Comment: Thanks for coming back and updating